# Email Regex validator not allowing return

Tags: regex, validation, email

I have this regex validation expression in an HTML text area to avoid users to type email addresses there:

```
/.*^((?![a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+).)*$/
```

The validator works fine, however, when a return is typed, the expression wouldn't allow any more text. Something like:

> Line 1 here (no email, so all good)
>
> [no more input allowed after the return]

Tried to research but couldn't find anything helpful, thanks in advance!

Comment: The regex doesn't make much sense especially the beginning `.*^`. If you're using javascript then replace that with `^[\s\S]*`. My first guess anyway since `.` doesn't match newlines.

Comment: Actually, the `.*^` part matches the start of string here, always. The regex matches a string that does not look like an email. If the anchors match the line boundaries, then it will only fail the line (if any line resembles an email). Please provide some code behind it.

Comment: if users add some spacing or replace the '@' e.g. with '[at]' it will still be possible to enter human readable eMail addresses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
^((?![a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)[\s\S])*$
                                                     ^^^^^^
```

The `.` does not match line break characters.

See [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLxjz9fo/).

Note that the *tempered greedy token* is a resource consuming pattern, I'd rather suggest using a simple lookahead solution:

```
^(?![\s\S]*?[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)[\s\S]*
```

See [this JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLxjz9fo/1/).

Here, `^` will assert the start of string, `(?![\s\S]*?[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[.][a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)` negative lookahead will fail the match once an email-like string is found in the text area, and `[\s\S]*` will match the whole contents (if your implementation requires the entire string match, if not - remove it).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Replacing the "." by "[\s\S])" made the job.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)). After getting 15 points, you can upvote on SO.